How might non-terrestrial environments promote health better than Earth-like conditions?
Is Earth Normal as good as it gets for Normal Earthlings? Most of the literature on non-Earth-like environments focuses on health hazards, not benefits, which makes sense. But there are some counter-examples even within the constraints of real life and this planet which improve our health. For instance, avoiding Earth Normal sun exposure and supplementing vitamin D reduces risk of certain skin diseases, and bright indoor lighting after Earth Normal sunset treats seasonal affective disorder.
Suppose we are free to choose a habitat's environmental conditions in other ways. Ways that are impossible, extremely difficult, or just overlooked on Earth, but which might plausibly be found or created elsewhere, on a space station, moon base, exoplanet, or otherwise extraterrestrial environment. Are there any differences from Earth Normal which might plausibly promote improved average lifetime health and longevity outcomes for large scale permanent human habitation?
For example, differences in atmospheric pressure or composition, gravity, spectrum and brightness of "outdoor" lighting, etc. Or even differences in the time or space derivatives of the same: On Earth I can't work in 1.5 gravities and sleep in 0.4 gravities, but I could do that on a rotating space station.
Being able to remain healthy upon returning to Earth-like conditions is not a requirement.
Weakly science-based. I'm just looking for plausible ideas, they don't have to be backed up by strong evidence or stand up to expert scrutiny.

Can you be more specific? Looking for ideas without a precise scope is not exactly what we answer here.

Simply an unpolluted atmosphere and abscence of microplastics in food chain, will give your people extended lifetime.

@L.Dutch I can self-VTC and post a new Q narrowing down to just gravity or something similar if you think that's appropriate.

Yeah, VTC:Needs More Focus for being open-ended brainstorming (see [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]). Remember that SE uses a one-specific-question/one-best-answer model. If you can't explain how you'll judge the one best answer, the question isn't ready for prime time.

BTW. I think there is an excellent question in here somewhere. Before posting anew, do some research on things like oxygen bars and why offices are painted specific colors and aroma therapy. I think there would be something like a "NASA-certified Mayo Clinic-approved deep space environmental design," but I expect you'll be asking about it one question at a time to get to it.

@dmcontador and a complete lack of PFOA, PFAS and other fluorocarbon chains. It's estimated that 99% of all human beings have been contaminated by these chemicals. Contamination has been found in both the Arctic and the Antarctic. And they cause or contribute to several nasty diseases, including cancer.

Okay, self-VTC it is, since there are existing answers.

If a planet is just like Earth but with milder natural disasters, does that make it non-Earth-like?  I mean, volcanoes, earthquakes, fires, hurricanes -- that's all written on the travel brochure when traveling to Earth.

In general, evolution has optimized us humans rather well to the environment, with one major caveat: "optimization" means you get old enough to have kids before you die. Because of this, there are a lot of things that disproportionately affect old people (eg sun exposure, cancer) however they weren't filtered out by evolution because these issues didn't pose serious survival consequences that prevented procreation.
Here are some that spring to mind:
Variable Gravity
If we had the ability to adjust gravity, or different gravitational zones, health benefits could be feasible.
In young people, higher gravity may be useful, as it could facilitate denser bone growth and a more robust musculoskeletal system. Particularly during childhood, growing up in a slightly higher gravity could grant life-long benefits.
For old people, lower gravity may be healthy, as it reduces wear on joints and strain on the cardiovascular system which has to pump blood against the force of gravity. In fact, I think it is reasonably plausible that when Moon colonization kicks off in the next 100 years, a significant portion of the "permanent residents" will be wealthy retirees, who want to live out the remainder of their life in a joint-pain free, low gravity environment.
Besides old people, just for regular people it may be beneficial to sleep in reduced gravity, as this could result in unmatched sleep quality and comfort.
Illumination
You touched on this, but natural sunlight is not really good for us. Exposure causes all sorts of long and short term issues (skin cancer, sunburn) and even cosmetic issues (wrinkling). While is utilized by the body in, for example, creating vitamin D, this is nothing that can't be replaced with simple supplements, and an illumination system which is safe is very doable.
Atmospheric control
In many indoor places here on Earth, there is a moderately serious problem of CO2 buildup from too many people exhaling. Studies show that even unnoticed increases in CO2 above the norm rapidly lead to decline in cognitive function and, in extreme cases headaches and similar symptoms. An environment in which the CO2 concentration can be precisely controlled may, therefore, lead to increased cognitive performance.
Similarly, you can likely fiddle with the O2 content and increase it slightly (not too much though, to prevent toxicity) as this has also shown to provide increased athletic and cognitive ability, at least in the short term.
Day/Night cycle
Sleep is still remarkably poorly understood, and sleep science is a very hot area of investigation, but it is conceivable that a 24 hour cycle is not actually the ideal cycle for humans. In a fully controlled environment, where the lighting and day cycle can be adjusted, it may turn out that (for example) a 26-hour day results in more rested, productive, and healthy individuals.
Controlled Toxin and Allergen-Free Atmosphere
While a sterile environment is not necessarily the best for humans, because humans who grow up in highly clean environments typically have poor disease resistances (kids eating their boogers and putting everything in their mouth builds up resitances), in a fully controlled environment you could likely significantly cut down on irritants like pollen or other microscopic hazards that humans on Earth regularly contend with.

most of the best points were already covered, so I focus a bit on the fact than a non terrestrial colony will be, by default, a high-tech colony of astronauts.

artificial selection: space colonists are effectively all ex-astronauts, and would go through the same rigorous selection process and training before even leaving the Earth. So your average colonist starts as an adult in their absolute peak physical and mental condition. There are no fat people in space, nor there are people with serious diseases, so the population by default starts as a maximum Eugenics experiment.
A space colony can, and would, be meticulously designed to maximize the health of the colonists. There would be no back-breaking chairs in the whole colony, and not a single drop of unhealthy corn-syrup. Nobody would ever miss their heath checkup, on the pain of being sent to the brig. Nobody would ever skip exercise, or fail to take their vitamins, because jeopardizing your health is jeopardizing the safety of everyone who depends on you to do your job. SO basically, colonists would live through a life long military bootcamp, except one run by friendly and reasonable nerds.
emotional and psychological health: not only would the colonists be selected to be perfectly sane, ice-cold rational stoics who can handle emergencies with optimal efficiency, but they would also be given the best counseling and therapy space-credits can buy, because if they ever flied off the handle due to some emotional crisis they could easily jeopardize the survival of the whole colony. Most importantly though, most colonists would have very similar personalities by default: a colony on an alien planet does not need ornery hotheads, or creative but lazy daydreamers, it needs a whole bunch of calm, collected, meticulous, workaholic nerds who function well under pressure and find joy in orderly perfectionism.

It almost does not matter what are the actual conditions on the alien planet, as long as they are alien and dangerous enough to keep the colony in permanent "Astronaut Mode" and attract only colonists who are essentially Mr Spock.
